# Label keeps disappearing from my navigation menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

For some reason the label in my navigation bar keeps disappearing and only displaying my map icon and home button. Is it because I'm adding it as a barbuttonitem? Is there a way around this?

```
UIView *view1=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 5, 250, 70)];
    UILabel *l1=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,5, 310, 70)];
    l1.text=@"FIND THINGS TO DO";
    l1.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue LT Std" size:25.0];
    l1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    l1.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    l1.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [view1 addSubview:l1];
    UIBarButtonItem *left2=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:view1];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=left2;
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES]; 

    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

    UIImage* image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home_btn.png"];
    homeBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 18, 38, 38)];
    [homeBtn setBackgroundImage:image3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [homeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(Home)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [homeBtn setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];

    UIBarButtonItem *home = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:homeBtn];
    NSArray *arr=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:home, nil];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = arr;

    UIImage* mapButton1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Top-Map-Icon.png"];
    mapButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 18, 26, 30)];
    [mapButton setBackgroundImage:mapButton1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [mapButton addTarget:self action:@selector(Map)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [mapButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];

    UIBarButtonItem *map = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:mapButton];
    NSArray *arr2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:map, nil];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = arr2;
```

Comment: Maybe your text in too long, when you add bar button, your text has not enough place to appear?

Comment: Yeah I tried changing the UIView size as well as the label size and to no avail.